# suspend vmware-player machine by script

Tags: vmware-player

Is there any way that I can use a script (batch or similar) to suspend all my running virtual machines?
For *vmware-workstation* vmrun.exe is the solution, but I only have *vmware-player*...

Purpose is to allow automatic drive backups.

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to VMware Workstation Pro to use "vmrun.exe" . I use VMware Workstation here and that comes with VMware Player as well.

How many machines do you have running simultaneously?  I usually do not have more than 3 at one time. So it is easy and fast to click on the Suspend Icon 3 times.  This may work for you.

If you need or much prefer the command line, or you need script automation, then you need to use VMware Workstation Pro.

Comment: too bad. Of course I can suspend them by hand, but as part of a backup solution I wanted to automate it

Comment: To automate the process, you need to upgrade to Workstation Pro. Player cannot do this.